# undefined reference to _imp_sfBlendAlpha

Tags: c, sfml

I have recently installed MinGW and CSFML on my laptop and I run:

```
gcc shaders.c -csfml-system -csfml-graphics
```

I get an error:

```
...\ccV1NsAK.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x247):' undefined reference to _imp__sfBlendAlpha'
```

How do I fix this?
Kind Regards,
Boston Brooks.

---

**Update 1**
I've played around with installing to different search paths but I couldn't get this to work. I reinstalled MinGW and pasted the files from the CSFML package to the default path. Now I get:

```
gcc shaders.c -lcsfml-system -lcsfml-window -lcsfml-graphics
C:\Users\bbroo\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9QM4Nx.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to '_imp__sfBlendAlpha'
C:\Users\bbroo\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9QM4Nx.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x318): undefined reference to '_imp__sfTransform_Identity'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

**Update 2**
I copied CSFML to my home folder. I get:

```
$ gcc -B ~/CSFML -Ld: ~/CSFML shaders.c  -lcsfml-system -lcsfml-window -lcsfml-graphics
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/bbroo/CSFML: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcsfml-system
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcsfml-window
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcsfml-graphics
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The header files can be accessed but the dot-a files are 'permission denied'
How do I set the permissions to Read-Write-Execute for all users on all files in CSFML using MSYS?

Same problem if I use C:\SFML

---

**Update 3**
When I unzip the files to the default path, a sub-folder is generated in the folder where my dot-a files are located. It contains several dot-a files, and a readme text file.

This README file is copied into the directory for GCC-only header files
when fixincludes is run by the makefile for GCC:

> Many of the files in this directory were automatically edited from the
>   standard system header files by the fixincludes process.  They are
>   system-specific, and will not work on any other kind of system.  They
>   are also not part of GCC.  The reason we have to do this is because
>   GCC requires ANSI C headers and many vendors supply ANSI-incompatible
>   headers.
>
> Because this is an automated process, sometimes headers get "fixed"
>   that do not, strictly speaking, need a fix.  As long as nothing is broken
>   by the process, it is just an unfortunate collateral inconvenience.
>   We would like to rectify it, if it is not "too inconvenient".

---

**Update 4**
Compiling without linking worked fine but linking separately didn't work:

```
bbroo@DESKTOP-1F1J3SM ~/Shaders
$ ld shaders.o libcsfml-system.a libcsfml-window.a libcsfml-graphics.a
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__main'
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `_imp__sfBlendAlpha'
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x318): undefined reference to `_imp__sfTransform_Identity'
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `sleep'
```

---

**Update 5**
Now I get:

```
bbroo@DESKTOP-1F1J3SM ~/Shaders
$ ld shaders.o libcsfml-system.a libcsfml-window.a libcsfml-graphics.a csfml-system-2.dll csfml-window-2.dll csfml-graphics-2.dll
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__main'
shaders.o:shaders.c:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `sleep'
```

Comment: Is this specific to sfBlendAlpha only? You could try defining it yourself as shown in [BlendMode](https://github.com/SFML/CSFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/BlendMode.cpp). If this is the first time you try using CSFML in your code then it could be that the compiler doesn't find your libraries, specifically sfBlendAlpha in this case. Are you using a non-standard path? Please describe how you installed CSFML.

Comment: I just unzipped the csfml package and pasted the files to the default path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc shaders.c libcsfml-system.a libcsfml-window.a libcsfml-graphics.a csfml-system-2.dll csfml-window-2.dll csfml-graphics-2.dll`

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a linking error. You could have made a mistake while linking the SFML libraries. Linking the libraries can be different for every IDE.

Follow a tutorial for setting up the SFML library that matches your IDE.

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorials for installing CSFML on MinGW. I just copied and pasted the files to the MinGW directory, which has worked for me in the past.

Comment: "Since it's a C library, there's only one archive per OS/architecture, which works for any compiler. The Windows archive contains the import libraries for Visual C++ and MinGW (gcc); those are compatible with every version of the corresponding compiler. " so I have the right version on csfml

Comment: I reinstalled MinGW and an older version of CSFML. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your command to compile :
    gcc shaders.c -csfml-system -csfml-grphics

You may miss-written it (ie -csfml-graphics) no ?

Comment: No i miss-wrote it when asking the question only.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial here: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php

Under the linker section screenshot, the tutorial mentions 3 libraries that needs to be linked in, which will translate to the command line arguments you need to add at the linking stage:

```
-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

You might also need to tell the linker where to find the libraries, which you will need to adjust to where they are on your machine, e.g.

-Ld:\smfl-2.0\lib

Comment: I copied the dot-a files to \lib and included the line -Ld\lib but no dice.